# Wrong format Transaction ID

Tags: blockchain.info

I have a BTC block chain which is stuck (3 weeks). I am using blockchaininfo .When I enter two of the transaction IDs ( cut and pasted ) it reports wrong format . A third transaction hashtag is accepted and reported to be confirmed. What is happening?

Comment: What are the three transaction IDs?

Comment: Hello Ian, welcome to Bitcoin SE. It's difficult for me to tell what you're asking. You say that you have a stuck transaction and seem to be asking about an unrelated issue with broken transaction ids. Could you please elaborate the significance of the various pieces of data, or perhaps even provide them so that we can take a look around ourselves? I've put the question on hold, but please do edit additional information into it and flag for reopening.